Where do you suggest that keyboard constants be added to Javascript?
I saw this code here:
myCombobox.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Escape') {
    myCombobox.close();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});

My education and experience tells me that the code should be comparing a constant.
myCombobox.addEventListener(MouseEvents.KEYDOWN, function(event) {
  if (event.key === KeyboardConstants.ESCAPE) {
    myCombobox.close();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});

Is there a class or object in JavaScript that has a list of all the keys and keyboard events on it?
Other languages do this for very obvious specific reasons, to prevent typos, which prevent errors and non-functioning code.
Does Javascript love errors or do these classes exist and I couldn't find them?
I tried to suggest this to TC39 and they said it's not a language feature. Where do I suggest this feature?

Named constants are useful to avoid magic numbers. But when the value is a string, there's not much gained by using a named constant -- the string values are self-documenting.

I don't think there are any named constants for these things. You can see the values documented in MDN

KeyboardEvent is part of the DOM specification, not EcmaScript. Do you should suggest it to W3C, not TC39.

MouseEvents.KEYDOWN? that's more confusing than helpful

Using constants are important to prevent typos. It doesn't matter if it's a string or a number. Comparing a string to constant prevents errors,  event.key=="keydown" would fail where event.key==KeyboardEvents.KEYDOWN would prevent it.

@JaromandaX that was a typo. It should be KeyboardEvents not MouseEvents. If there were keyboard constants, tooling would have helped exclude that error right at the start. Thank you for proving my point.

@1.21gigawatts not sure pointing out that you used a completely different word proves your pint.

If you really want to make this suggestion, you can make it here:
https://github.com/w3c/uievents-code/issues/
You can refer to this list whenever you need:
https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-code/#key-alphanumeric-writing-system
There's all the current KeyboardEvent codes described there.

Nothing stopping you from creating your own list of event.key string values...
For a start:
const KeyboardConstants = Object.freeze( 
  { BACKSPACE  : 'Backspace'
  , TAB        : 'Tab'
  , ENTER      : 'Enter'
  , ESCAPE     : 'Escape'
  , SPACE      : 'Space'
  , PAGE_UP    : 'PageUp'
  , PAGE_DOWN  : 'PageDown'
  , END        : 'End'
  , HOME       : 'Home'
  , LEFT       : 'ArrowLeft'
  , UP         : 'ArrowUp'
  , RIGHT      : 'ArrowRight'
  , DOWN       : 'ArrowDown'
  , INSERT     : 'Insert'
  , DELETE     : 'Delete'
  // ...
  });

